# Client socket doesn't close if internet on client side was disconnected. How detect this event in the server?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Client server application on c++.
If client close programm , socket cloded but, if internet on client side was disconnected, socket doesn`t close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no choice: you have to wait for the TCP timeout. When the timeout happens, your server socket will get closed *as if* the client had properly closed the connection (give or take the status/error code).

Depending on the settings of your server's TCP stack, it can take quite a while (I have seen systems where it took 30 minutes...). Just be patient.

Comment: If the server sends something to the client regularly (a null message of some sort), it tends to detect the disconnection quicker - because of the lack of ACKs from the other end.

Comment: @Alan Good point. This should indeed help most TCP stacks detect the connection loss. The only downside is that it requires application support, but it's not dramatic. I also seem to recall TCP supports an out of band "keep-alive" option which helps avoid timeouts when no data is transferred, and should also help the TCP stack detect a disconnection. But I never used it so I'm not sure if this applies.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of that too, but I've also been advised not to mess with it. A bonus advantage of the explicit server-generated keepalive is that the client can detect if the server has gone away.

Comment: @Alan re. built-in TCP keep-alive, [according to this document](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html): *Keepalive is non-invasive, and in most cases, if you're in doubt, you can turn it on without the risk of doing something wrong. But do remember that it generates extra network traffic, which can have an impact on routers and firewalls.* Apart this extra traffic, I wonder what other bad implications it could have? (yeah, you triggered my curiosity saying "not to mess with it") ;)

Comment: The server-side socket will not 'get' closed. The server application has to detect a read timeout or IOException when reading or writing it, and close it itself.

Comment: @EJP I don't know about "*IOException*" (it certainly isn't any standard C++ or BSD sockets stuff), what I meant is that the timeout error will use the very same code path as a regular client-side disconnection so you don't have to add specific code for it.